# What is the significance of Go's time.Format(layout string) reference time?

Tags: go

What is the significance of Go's time.Format(layout string) reference time, ie:

*Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006*

This specific time couldn't have been chosen completely randomly, right?

Source: http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format

Comment: hint, try using the numeric values for each part

Comment: Hahaha wish I had looked a little closer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Each part of the date is used as an index:

```
Jan        -> 1      -> Month
2          -> 2      -> Day-of-Month
15 = 3PM   -> 15/3   -> hour
04         -> 4      -> minute
05         -> 5      -> second
2006       -> 6      -> year
-0700      -> 7      -> time-zone
```

So according to the doc:

> Since MST is GMT-0700, the reference time can be thought of as
> 01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700

This makes it easy for the `time.Format` method to parse human-readable date format specifications that are visually identical to the desired result.

Compare this to for example the `strftime` C function that uses hard-to-remember format strings such as `"%a, %d %b %y %T %z"` which represents a RFC 822-compliant date format.

The Go equivalent is: `"Mon, 02 Jan 06 15:04 MST"`.

The `time.Format` will tokenize this string and analyze each word.

- Mon is recognized litteraly as monday so this is the week day's name
- the comma is left untouched
- 02 is recognized as the integer value 2, representing a day-of-month in the index
- Jan is the known english abbreviation for the january month, so this is used for the month part
- 06 is 6 so this the year part
- 15 is equivalent to 3 and represent the hour
- the `':'` character is left untouched
- 04 is 4, therefore the minute
- MST is interpreted litteraly

See https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.15/src/time/format.go#L151 for the exact algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

In American date format, it's `Mon, 1/2 03:04:05 PM 2006 -0700`.

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.